# Word request: how to refer to the time when schools close in a day?

Tags: word-request

I want to describe the time in the afternoon when schools close, but I'm not sure if "close" is the right word here. for example:

> I'm sitting at a cafe, looking at the window, waiting for the streets to fill with children when the schools close.

Comment: Just a tiny thing to note, "looking *at* the window" can be rephrased to improve the sentence (e.g., looking outside through the window). Also, you could say "... waiting for the streets to fill with children when the last period ends"

Comment: look out a window, we say.

Answer (score 4):

Schools are said to let out.

when the schools let out.

**What time does your school let out?**

AmE

Let out in BrE can mean to rent out [a room or apartment or house, etc.].

let out is a phrasal verb:

[all the meanings of let out](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/let-out_1)

to let out means: to allow a person or animal to leave a place when they have been confined to it, literally or not.

Comment: In this context, "let out" is short for "let the students out".

Comment: Who let the dogs out?

Comment: It is important to note that 'let out' sounds quite formal, however you are correct, it is grammatically correct.

Comment: schools let kids out [at some time], kids get out [at some time]. I don't see the formality...